# Spectral decomposition and a harmonic osillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, perturbation-theory

A system is described by a Hamiltonian $$H^0=\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{m\omega^2}{2}x^2.$$
A perturbation in the form of $$H'=\lambda \frac{4m^2\omega^2}{\hbar}x^4$$ is applied.
I showed that $H'=\hbar\omega(a_++a_{-})^4$ with $a_{\pm}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\hbar m \omega}}(\mp ip+m\omega x)$.
After this I need to show that  $$(a_++a_{-})^4=\sum^\infty_{n=0}(c_0(n) |n\rangle \langle n |) +\sum^\infty_{n=1}(c_2(n) |n+1\rangle \langle n-1 |+ h.c.)\sum^\infty_{n=2}(c_4(n) |n+2\rangle \langle n-2 |+ \text{h.c.}),$$
where h.c. is the hermitian conjugate and $c_0=3(2n(n+1)+1)$, $c_2(n)=\sqrt{n(n+1)}(4n+2)$ and $c_4(n)=\sqrt{(n+2)(n+1)n(n-1)}$.
We have proven that earlier on that a operator can be written as a spectral decomposition $$\hat{Q}=\sum_n q_n |\sigma_n\rangle\langle \sigma_n|$$
And I have worked out all the terms for the $(a_++a_-)^4$ product and what they would have done with state $|n\rangle$. I however have no idea how to get to $(a_++a_-)^4=...$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start noticing that
\begin{equation}
\left(a \ + \ a^{\dagger} \right)^2 = a^2 \ + \ 2 \ a^{\dagger} \ a \ + \ 1 \ + \ a^{\dagger 2} \, .
\end{equation}

Consider now the fact that
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle n| \left(a \ + \ a^{\dagger} \right)^4 | k \rangle &=& \langle n| \left(a \ + \ a^{\dagger} \right)^2 \left(a \ + \ a^{\dagger} \right)^2 | k \rangle
\\
&=& \left[ \left(a \ + \ a^{\dagger} \right)^{2 \dagger} |n\rangle \right]^{\dagger}  \left(a \ + \ a^{\dagger} \right)^{2} |k\rangle
\\
&=& \left[ \left(a \ + \ a^{\dagger} \right)^{2} |n\rangle \right]^{\dagger}  \left(a \ + \ a^{\dagger} \right)^{2} |k\rangle \ , \label{split2}
\end{eqnarray}
where in the last line we used the fact that $\left(a \ + \ a^{\dagger}\right) $ is self-adjoint.

We can compute all the matrix elements we need by using this split, knowing the standar action of creation and annihilation operators over $|n\rangle$ states. This is
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle n| \left(a \ + \ a^{\dagger} \right)^4 | k \rangle &=& \left[ \left(a \ + \ a^{\dagger} \right)^{2} |n\rangle \right]^{\dagger} \left[ \left(a \ + \ a^{\dagger} \right)^{2} |k\rangle \right] \nonumber
\\
&=& \left[\sqrt{n(n-1)} \ |n-2\rangle \ + \ (2n \ + \ 1) \ |n\rangle \ + \ \sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)} \ |n+2\rangle \right]^{\dagger}  \nonumber
\\
&& \times \left[\sqrt{k(k-1)} \ |k-2\rangle \ + \ (2k \ + \ 1) \ |k\rangle \ + \ \sqrt{(k+1)(k+2)} \ |k+2\rangle  \right] \nonumber
\\
&=& \left[\sqrt{n(n-1)} \ \langle n-2| \ + \ (2n \ + \ 1) \ \langle n| \ + \ \sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)} \ \langle n+2| \right]  \nonumber
\\
&& \times \left[\sqrt{k(k-1)} \ |k-2\rangle \ + \ (2k \ + \ 1) \ |k\rangle \ + \ \sqrt{(k+1)(k+2)} \ |k+2\rangle  \right] \nonumber
\\
&=& \begin{cases} 
\sqrt{k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)} &, \ n = k - 4
\\ 
2(2k-1)\sqrt{k(k-1)} &, \ n = k -2 
\\ 
3(2k^2+2k+1) &, \ n = k
\\
2(2k+3)\sqrt{(k+1)(k+2)} &, \ n = k + 2 
\\
\sqrt{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)} &, \ n = k +4
\\
0 &, \ \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}  \ ,
\end{eqnarray}
 where we used the fact that the set of eigenstates is orthonormal. As you mention, this can be summarized in the spectral decomposition of the operator. To do this, we use the spectral decomposition of the identity operator,$\, 1\, = \, \sum_{\mathrm{All} \, n} |n\rangle \langle n|$ , and write, for an arbitrary operator $A$,
\begin{equation}
A= 1 \, \times \, A \, \times \, 1 = \sum_{\mathrm{All} \, n} |n\rangle \langle n| \, A  \, \sum_{\mathrm{All} \, k} |k\rangle \langle k| = \sum_{\mathrm{All} \, n} \sum_{\mathrm{All} \, k} \, \langle n| A |k\rangle \, |n\rangle \langle k| \, .
\end{equation}

Using this for the operator of interest and switching some of the summation indices, you'll be able to recover the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a mistake in your question. Are you supposed to compute $(a_+ a_-)^4$ or $(a_+ + a_-)^4$ ? 
Whatever the task is - write down the ladder operators in their spectral form and form the pairs. Only the ones shown above will remain.

Comment: Unfortunately I forgot to put the plus in there, it should be fixed now.

Comment: No. The $x^4$ hamiltonian as originally stated *does* correspond to the sum, not the product, inside the power.

Comment: You are right... Edited the post.